# Injected CSS from Code-Behind into ASP.NET WebForm

Tags: css, webforms

I have a situation where my H3 tags are styled in an external CSS file, but the color attribute is going to dynamically change based on a database value.  I would like to inject some CSS into my master page from code-behind to set the color of the H3 tag globally instead of having to specify it on each tag.

How can I do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize I could put controls in the style section.  Here's how I resolved the problem:

```
<style>
   h3 
   {
      color:<asp:Literal runat="server" id="ColorLiteral" />;
   }
</style>
```

Now I set the literal from code-behind and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

try the !important css attribute

Comment: My question was specific to adding the dynamic css value.  I solved it and will post the answer.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are getting at now.  Good note.  Luckily I just removed the color element from my static CSS file so I didn't have this issue.